# How find the value of $(a_0-a_2+a_4-\ldots)^2+(a_1-a_3+ \ldots)^2$ using $(1+x)^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_nx^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Q) $(1+x)^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_nx^n$ then $(a_0-a_2+a_4-\ldots)^2+(a_1-a_3+
> \ldots)^2$ is equals to 
> 1. 1
> 2. 0 (zero)
> 3. $2^{n-1}$
> 4. $2^n$

**Answer: (4)**

well this time i am rocked by this question... sorry for that

can you please give me a hint or a certain logic using which **i** could solve this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

\begin{align*}
(1+x)^n & = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+ \dotsb +a_nx^n\\
(1-x)^n & = a_0-a_1x+a_2x^2-a_3x^3+ \dotsb +(-1)^na_nx^n\\
\end{align*}
Then 
$$\frac{(1+x)^n+(1-x)^n}{2}  = a_0+a_2x^2+a_4x^4+\dotsb$$
Now substitute $x=i$ to get
\begin{align*}
\frac{(1+i)^n+(1-i)^n}{2}  & = a_0-a_2+a_4+\dotsb \\
(\sqrt{2})^n \cos \frac{n\pi}{4}  & = a_0-a_2+a_4+\dotsb \\
2^{n} \cos^2 \frac{n\pi}{4}  & = (a_0-a_2+a_4+\dotsb)^2 \\
\end{align*}
Now take a similar approach to get the second expression.